# Lodash-esque Iteratee Type

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a method that iterates over an Array of objects and I want to have the ability to use an `iteratee` in a fashion similar to how lodash uses `iteratee`s. That is, I want an `iteratee` to be either a key of the object, or a function that takes the object and returns a value. Additionally, I want to be able to constrain the type of the resulting value.

First I need the ability to get all keys of a type that correspond to a specific value type.

```
type KeysCorrespondingToValueType<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

Next I define the `Iteratee` type.

```
type Iteratee<T, V> = KeysCorrespondingToValueType<T, V> | ((item: T) => V);
```

Finally I have a function that takes an object of type `T` and an `Iteratee` and returns a value.

```
function getNumericValueFromIteratee<T>(
  item: T,
  iteratee: Iteratee<T, number>
): number {
  return typeof iteratee === 'function' ? iteratee(item) : item[iteratee];
}
```

However TypeScript complains with

```
Type 'number | T[KeysCorrespondingToValueType<T, number>]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'T[KeysCorrespondingToValueType<T, number>]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'T[T[keyof T] extends number ? keyof T : never]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
          Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: You sure can do that with `<K extends keyof T, T extends Record<K, number>>(I: T, iter: K | T=>number)`

Comment: @Dimava this will only work if I'm working exclusively with objects of type `Record<K, number>`. It won't work with interfaces or object types with non-numeric values.

Comment: Christopher Fimbel, no it will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getNumericValueFromIteratee<
  T extends Record<K, number>,
  K extends keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends number ? K : never]: 1 },
>(
  item: T,
  iteratee: K | ((t: T) => number)
): number {
  return typeof iteratee === 'function' ? iteratee(item) : item[iteratee];
}

getNumericValueFromIteratee({ a: 1, b: 'foo' }, 'b')
getNumericValueFromIteratee({ a: 1, b: 'foo' }, 'b') //err
getNumericValueFromIteratee({ a: 1, b: 'foo' }, 'c') //err
```

This works, because

- `T[K]` is guaranteed to be a `number` because `T extends Record<K, number>`
- `T extends Record<K, number>` doesn't have to be `Record<string, number>`
- `K extends string` would work fine as well, but won't have autocompletion

Comment: Ah, I think when you commented the first time I misunderstood `T extends Record<K, number>` as being equivalent to `<Record<K, Number>>`. Thank you for your help!